# How to perform transition programmatically between SwapView in dojo?

Tags: dojo

I would like to perform a transtion programmatically from one SwapView to another one in dojo;

How to do this ?

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least a couple of options. You can use the `goTo(dir, moveTo)` method or `performTransition(moveTo, transitionDir, transition, context, method)` which is inherited from `dojox/mobile/View` [API link to SwapView](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.9/dojox/mobile/SwapView)

Here are a couple of examples:

```
var homeView = dijit.registry.byId("home");
//this
homeView.performTransition("someView", 1, "slide"); //slide from right to left
//or this
homeView.goTo(1, "someView");
```

Note: To slide from left to right, set the direction parameter to -1